# Rails 3 submit a form with multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails so this is probably a basic question.  I am trying to create a form where the user can create 3 records at once.  I want the user to only have to click the submit button once.  I'm submitting to my Review model a name, comment, and rating.  Currently, only the last record is entered into the database.

```
<%= form_for([@user,@review]) do |f| %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Rank</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Comment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :comment %></td>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rating, :value=> "5" %>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :comment %></td>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rating, :value=> "3" %> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :comment %></td>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rating, :value=> "1" %>
  </tr>
</table>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create my top 3" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would recommend using `fields_for` for this:

```
<%= form_for([@user, :reviews]) do |f| %>
  <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <%= fields_for review do |r| %>
      <%= render "reviews/form", :r => r %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To make this work, you will need to build as many review objects as you require in your controller:

```
def new
  # you could also have this in a before_filter...
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @reviews = Array.new(3) { @user.reviews.build }
end
```

This would create new *instances* of review records for this user, which is different from new *records*. Instances are simply Ruby objects. Now because you've called `@user.reviews.build` three times, you'll see three reviews in your view.

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  @reviews = Review.create(params[:reviews])
  # Some more logic for validating the parameters passed in
end
```

This will create three new `Review` objects and link them to `@user`, assuming all three are valid.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by your post.  The current page that I posted is the reviews#new page, so is the def new in the reviews controller what you are calling "the_action" and likewise whatever_this_is is the def create in the reviews controller?

Also where you put 'render/form' what is in render form? Currently, :url => reviews_path) is giving me a name error.  Thanks.

Comment: what if you don't know how many records are needed. ex. user can 'add new row' to the form for additional entries.

Comment: Take a look here for adding a new row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919711/multiple-non-nested-model-creation-on-same-page/16920211#comment24427696_16920211

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to tell rails its an array. First, [read this section of this article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#basic-structures):

For your purpose, you'll need to build the form by hand:

```
<%= form_tag 'foo' do %>
  <% [1,3,5].each do |i| %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'review[][name]' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'review[][comment]' %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'review[][rating]', :value => i %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: OP should use fields_for with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for this.

Comment: Umm... Does it really matter? This accomplishes the same thing AND this is how the Rails guides do it. Really worth a downvote when it will function correctly?

Comment: I've read the article you linked and a few others, but I'm still having problems getting this too work.  The form is rendering correctly, but the 'foo' part is giving me problems.  I have replaced foo with user_review_path but it is giving me a routing error?  Is there something else I have to do in the new or create controllers or routing file?

Comment: You'll need to define a route. Are you nesting :review inside :user. Run the command `rake routes` from within your application's directory and see what names paths you have