# Rails nested form build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I got a problem with nested form.
My controller is:

```
def new
    @encomenda = Encomenda.new
    @encomenda.encomenda_produtos.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @encomenda }
    end
end
```

My view is:

```
<ul id="invitelist">
  <li>
  <%= f.fields_for :encomenda_produtos do |a| %>
        <%= a.label :id_produto, t("activerecord.attributes.encomenda_produto.produto", :default => "Produto"), :class => :label %>
        <%= a.collection_select :id_produto, Produto.order('nome_produto'), :id_produto, :id_produto, :class => 'collection_select_field' %>
        <br><br>
  <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the Javascript is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#botao_novo_produto').click(function() {
        if ($('#invitelist li').length < 7)
            $('#invitelist li:last').clone().find('input').val('')
            .end().appendTo('#invitelist');
        else
            alert('Número máximo de produtos')
    });

        $('#botao_remove_produto').click(function() {
            if ($('#invitelist li').length > 1)
                $('#invitelist li:last').remove();
            else
                alert('Uma encomenda deve conter ao menos 1 produto.')
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem here is that I need to add '@encomenda.encomenda_produtos.build' every new item (product) I added in my view. If I use something like '3.times @encomenda.encomenda_produtos.build' it works well.
So, what should I do to have a dynamic form that I could add as many products I want?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I posted an answer few days ago about something similar:

[Multiple non-nested model creation on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919711/multiple-non-nested-model-creation-on-same-page/16920211#16920211)

With this code, **no AJAX call is made** and it is dynamic (you can add as many forms as you want).

> **Adding fields and keep only one form, one submit button:**

```
= form_tag(url: create_user_path, remote: true) do
  %table
    %tr
      %td= text_field_tag 'user[][first_name]'
      %td= text_field_tag 'user[][last_name]'

    %tr.actions
      %td= submit_tag 'Save'
      %td= button_tag 'Add new user form', id: 'add_user_form'

    %tr.new_user_row.hidden # 'hidden' class matches the css rule: display:none;
      %td= text_field_tag "user[][last_name]"
      %td= text_field_tag "user[][last_name]"

:javascript # jQuery
  $('#add_user_form').bind('click', function(e) {
    var row = $('tr.new_user_row').clone().removeClass('hidden new_user_row');
    $('tr.actions').before(row); # will append the <tr> before the actions
  });
```

In UsersController:

```
def create
  params[:user].each do |attr|
    User.create(attr)
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie and for me `nested_form gem` worked like butter without any headache 
Check out this [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)