# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have this model in Ruby but it throws a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => {:in => 3..20}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, :uniqueness => true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    end
  end

  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
  end
end
```

when I run this action

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You Signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
```

on `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]`.

Can you please tell me how to get rid of this error or establish a proper user registration form?

Comment: try with adding attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation,:user_name, :email, :your-other-attributes in the User model

Comment: Add *strong_parameter* gem to use *attr_accessible*.

Comment: strong parameters to use attr_accessible?!

Comment: I believe @BruceLi meant: Add the `protected_attributes` gem to use `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score 432, accepted):

I guess you are using Rails 4. If so, the needed parameters must be marked as required.

You might want to do it like this:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :salt, :encrypted_password)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there any documentation about why this works or why this is needed?

Comment: @OmarJackman The functionality is provided by the `strong_parameter` gem. It is covered in Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters.

Comment: People might be experiencing this if they use **CanCan** with Rails 4.0. Try [AntonTrapps's](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835#issuecomment-18663815) rather clean workaround solution until CanCan gets updated.

Comment: @mjnissim Would you please post this as a separate answer?  I missed it the first time through, but it still saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 65):

**For those using CanCan**. People might be experiencing this if they use **CanCan** with **Rails 4+**. Try [AntonTrapps's](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835#issuecomment-18663815) rather clean workaround solution [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835#issuecomment-18663815) until CanCan gets updated:

In the `ApplicationController`:

```
before_filter do
  resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
  method = "#{resource}_params"
  params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
end
```

and in the resource controller (for example NoteController):

```
private
def note_params
  params.require(:note).permit(:what, :ever)
end
```

**Update:**

Here's a continuation project for CanCan called **CanCanCan**, which looks promising:

[CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

Comment: Thanks!! I have a question, with CanCanCan (active) is solved or not need this code?

Comment: For me, CanCanCan still have the issue. Not using `load_resource` or use `load_resource :except => :create` solved the issue. Check the original answer [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/571#issuecomment-5427632)

Answer (score 29):

For those using **CanCanCan**:

You will get this error if CanCanCan cannot find the correct **params method**.

For the `:create` action, CanCan will try to initialize a new instance with sanitized input by seeing if your controller will respond to the following methods (in order):

1. `create_params`
2. `<model_name>_params` such as article_params (this is
   the default convention in rails for naming your param method)
3. `resource_params` (a generically named method you could specify in
   each controller)

Additionally, `load_and_authorize_resource` can now take a `param_method` option to specify a custom method in the controller to run to sanitize input.

You can associate the `param_method` option with a symbol corresponding to the name of a method that will get called:

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource param_method: :my_sanitizer

  def create
    if @article.save
      # hurray
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def my_sanitizer
    params.require(:article).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

source:
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#33-strong-parameters

Comment: Thanks. This was my problem. I refactored a model but left the params method the old name. Renamed and fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks. This saved me

Answer (score 25):

There is an easier way to avoid the Strong Parameters at all, you just need to convert the parameters to a regular hash, as:

```
unlocked_params = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(params)

model.create!(unlocked_params)
```

This defeats the purpose of strong parameters of course, but if you are in a situation like mine (I'm doing my own management of allowed params in another part of my system) this will get the job done.

Comment: Doesn't work in rails 6, exception: `unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash `

Answer (score 24):

If using ActiveAdmin don't forget that there is also a permit_params in the model register block:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Api::V1::Person do
  permit_params :name, :address, :etc
end
```

These need to be set along with those in the controller:

```
def api_v1_person_params
  params.require(:api_v1_person).permit(:name, :address, :etc)
end
```

Otherwise you will get the error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use the [Protected Attributes gem](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes), however this defeats the purpose of requiring strong params. However if you're upgrading an older app, Protected Attributes does provide an easy pathway to upgrade until such time that you can refactor the attr_accessible to strong params.

Answer (score 2):

One more reason is that you override `permitted_params` by a method. For example

```
def permitted_params
   params.permit(:email, :password)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Rails 4 and you get this error, it could happen if you are using `enum` on the model if you've defined with symbols like this:

```
class User
  enum preferred_phone: [:home_phone, :mobile_phone, :work_phone]
end
```

The form will pass say a radio selector as a string param. That's what happened in my case. The simple fix is to change `enum` to strings instead of symbols

```
enum preferred_phone: %w[home_phone mobile_phone work_phone]
# or more verbose
enum preferred_phone: ['home_phone', 'mobile_phone', 'work_phone']
```