# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
Extracted source (around line #3):

1. def create
2. @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
3. @comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
4. redirect_to @post
5. end
6. end

Rails.root: C:/Users/ManU/Desktop/quick_blog
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'

What i'm supposed to do to deal with this error.....
please give me soln with path as well...i don't have prior knowlwdge to this.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)

Comment: Using Windows to write rails applications? :)  If you are new, I would go get virtualbox and install ubuntu and write ruby there.  You get some nice features like FileUtils.rm, etc. if you are doing file manipulation ever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you appear to be following a pre rails 4.0  tutorial with rails 4.  You need to use strong params now.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

there is also a railscast on it that should help.

```
@comment = @post.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit!) 


@comment = @post.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit(:comment_text,:link))
```

The first will permit all params to be allowed,  the latter will only allow `comment_text` and `link` to be accepted.

Comment: You are missing the closing braces of the `.create!` methods.

Comment: Thanks ..I'm begginer and had suspect be a problem relation of Strong Params, so your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is throwing ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError, that means you must be using **strong_parameters** gem or your rails should have version greater than 4, in which case strong_parameters gem is already included in that version. In that case, you add the following code on your **application_controller.rb** to get rid off from this error.

```
before_filter do
  resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
  method = "#{resource}_params"
  params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
end
```