# Params Error (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm getting a "ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create" with highlights in "@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])"

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

in the tutorial video the coder puts this in and works perfect yet when I post this it gives an error. I have checked through the code and cannot to seem to see whats wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error, I am assuming that you must be using Rails 4. Strong Parameters were introduced in Rails 4. See [Strong Parameters](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/) reference here.

Replace

```
 @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

with

```
 @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
```

Add a private method in your controller as follows:

```
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:attr1, :attr2,...)
  end
```

where 
:attr1, :attr2 would be the attributes name of Comment model.

Comment: +1.. You are correct. similar post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user

Comment: I did replace it with  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params) but ended up getting another error, "NameError in Comments#index" with "<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>" and I know this is a valid path because of rake routes ):

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace in the question. Also share the index action.

Comment: Ah, I looked deeper and found the solution after trail and error. Thanks for the help! It fixed the error.