# rails4: cancan or cancancan? with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, cancan

I'm trying to implement some type of users so ones can edit data and other can only read.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    validates_presence_of :email, :password, :on => :create
end
```

I'm using **has_secure_password**(I followes http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1?view=asciicast) for sessions and I found **cancan** but I found this:

http://rubygems.org/gems/cancan and http://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan

so, what is the difference? which must I use?

is [this guide](http://jeremyjbarth.blogspot.com/2011/10/rails-31-simple-custom-authentication.html) for rails 3.1 and cancan a good start point or should I look for another approach?

I'm newbie with rails, thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#mission

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The CanCan project is dead and CanCanCan is a separate project to make a similar authorization solution for Rails 4.  In short, CanCan is suitable for Rails 3 apps and CanCanCan is suitable for Rails 4 apps.  Here is [another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user#answer-18766552) with some more information about CanCan / CanCanCan.

Comment: Is it possible to update this as it's not clear (although one could guess) what to do for rails 5 and 6 ?

Comment: @stevec - cancancan is still being updated.  They made [a Rails 6 release](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/commit/24f3b542dc8ac8a9ad831140648ec024215e956a) relatively recently.  I've been out of the Rails-world for quite some time, but cancancan still looks like a good option!