# Ruby on Rails -- ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following some Ruby on Rails tutorials, and I'm just simply trying to use the create method.

Here's my subjects controller:

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
    
    def list
        @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
    end

    def show
        @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def new
        @subject = Subject.new(:name => 'Default')
    end

    def create
        @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])
        if @subject.save
            redirect_to(:action => 'list')
        else
            render('new')
        end
    end
end
```

and here's the new.html.erb file:

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to list", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subject new">
    <h2>Create Subject</h2>

    <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

    <table summary="Subject form fields">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Position</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Visible</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:visib) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="form buttons">
        <%= submit_tag("Create Subject") %>
    </div>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

So when I go the localhost:3000/controller/new, I can see the form that shows the textfields just as I expect. However, the minute I try to submit it, I get to an error page that gives an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError error.

Here's the parameters that were submitted to the create action:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"rwzPJd9HG5p/F8Uz7iktOa2hOnmQdwYFoZTqKSskDbU=",
 "subject"=>{"name"=>"nothing",
 "position"=>"5",
 "visible"=>"false"},
 "commit"=>"Create Subject"}
```

If I went into rails console, then everything works fine if I try to do this exact same thing manually (I think at least?).

```
2.1.1 :016 > Subject.create({"name"=>"nothing",
2.1.1 :017 >        "position"=>"5",
2.1.1 :018 >        "visible"=>"false"})
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.2ms)  INSERT INTO `subjects` (`created_at`, `name`, `position`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-06-06 02:08:38', 'nothing', 5, '2014-06-06 02:08:38')
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Subject id: 11, name: "nothing", position: 5, visible: false, created_at: "2014-06-06 02:08:38", updated_at: "2014-06-06 02:08:38">
```

I'm still new to Rails.

Comment: If you are using `Rails4`,you should be using `strong params`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far. Although I've found a few articles pointing to how to fix this, I still believe I'm doing something wrong. I've changed one of the lines under the create method to this: @subject = Subject.new(params.required(:subject).permit(:visible, :position)). However, when I submit the POST request and view the data that was supposed to be created, I can see everything except for the Subject. The Subject shows as nil.

Comment: However, if I try to permit :subject, :visible, and :position, then everything that get posted turns into a nil....

Comment: This `params.required(:subject).permit(:visible,:position)` should be like this `params.require.(:subject).permit(:name,:visible,:position)`

Comment: Nevermind. Got it! I forgot to whitelist the :name parameter. Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing it like this

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  ........
  ........

  def create
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
    if @subject.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

  private

  def subject_params
    params.require.(:subject).permit(:name,:visible,:position)
  end

end
```

Have a look at **`Strong Parameters`** here in these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)**