# How can I pass a nested json object to rails from angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this:

```
$scope.create = function() {
    var theproperty = {
          businessName: this.businessName,
          streetAddress: this.streetAddress,
          city: this.city,
          state: this.state,
          zip: this.zip,
          mdu: this.mdu,
          units: this.units,
          content: this.content
    };

var propertywrap = {
      property: theproperty
    }
```

I sent that to the factory which passes it on to rails. Right now, def create just has this:

```
@property = Property.new(params[:property])
```

and then i have an if/else/end in case i get that far. But, until I can actually get it that far, I haven't worked on safe_params or anything yet. First things first, right?

The object that get's passed looks like this:

```
{"property":{"businessName":"test","streetAddress":"test thgis","city":"asdfqw4r","state":"qfa","zip":"asdfas","units":"asdfa","content":"asdfasdf"}}
```

And console log shows this:

```
Started POST "/properties" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-27 13:02:25 -0600
Processing by PropertiesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"property"=>{"businessName"=>"test from firefox", "streetAddress"=>"12 any st", "city"=>"clearfield", "state"=>"ut", "zip"=>"55445", "units"=>"adf",    "content"=>"asdfasdfasdf"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
```

But i'm getting a response back: **ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError**

I even tried forming my object to pass this way:

```
var propertywrap = {
      property : {
        businessName: this.businessName,
        streetAddress: this.streetAddress,
        city: this.city,
        state: this.state,
        zip: this.zip,
        mdu: this.mdu,
        units: this.units,
        content: this.content
      }
    }
```

But I still got the same error back.

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError at /properties
====================================================

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

Am I doing this completely crazy? What should I be doing?

Based on an answer below, I changed the params and the table to use underscore instead of camelcase. So, now i'm passing:

```
{"property":{"business_name":"something her","street_address":"960 s 550 e","city":"sometown","state":"te","zip":"85121","units":"adf","content":"asdfasdf asdfasdf"}}
```

I'm still getting the same error, though.

Comment: This is either strong parameters in controller, or for older rails versions unpermitted attributes in model

Comment: I'm using rails 4. How can I see if strong parameters are the issue?

Comment: Can you paste create method from controller and the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the reason of issue is camelcase of params like businessName and streetAddress. On rails side this properties should be business_name and street_address.

You can use 
https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource 
"By default we convert attribute names between underscore and camel case."

Comment: Ok, I changed the params that are getting posted to use underscores, I also updated the table to match that.

so, now i'm passing:

{"property":{"business_name":"something her","street_address":"960 s 550 e","city":"sometown","state":"te","zip":"85121","units":"adf","content":"asdfasdf asdfasdf"}}

Still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe you forgot about strong params in your controller, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17335871/905697

You should have something like this:

```
@property = Property.new(property_params)

def property_params
params.require(:property).permit(:business_name, :street_address) # add here rest
end
```

Comment: Do I have to have that? I thought it was optional? See in my ruby controller I may have it looking for the peppery params and I'm not using strong params.

Comment: Strong params are enabled by default for rails 4 app. You need to permit params before passing them to Propery constructor.
Check https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: guess what? that was it. I didn't realize that I HAD to set strong params. I thought it was optional. Once I did that it was perfect. I changed my action for new to create, set a private method for the params and I was golden. you can see my updated controller here: https://github.com/jshultz/rails-omniauth/blob/master/app/controllers/properties_controller.rb