# Rails: Error on form_tag custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

About a year and a half ago I took an online course in Ruby on Rails using version 3.2. I got through the class and made the application and now I'm going back through the class PDFs and doing it in Rails 4.1.0.

I've got to a section where I'm getting an error and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if something changed from Rails 3.2 to 4.1.

I've got this form_tag tag:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'review', :id => @restaurant do %>
  <strong>Poster: </strong><%= text_field "review", "poster" %><br /><br />
  <strong>Date: </strong><%= datetime_select "review", "date" %><br /><br />
  <strong>Review:</strong><br />
  <%= text_area "review", "review", :rows => 5 %><br />
  <%= submit_tag "Review" %>
<% end %>
```

The instructions say to get this to work to put the following code in the restaurants_controller.rb file:

```
def review
  Restaurant.find(params[:id]).reviews.create(params[:review])
  redirect_to :action=>"show", :id => params[:id]
end
```

But when I try and view the page that has the for for it I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"review", "controller=>"restaurants", :id=>#<Restaurant id: 1, name: "Marco & Luca", created_at: "...", updated_at: "..."
```

My rake routes shows that show is mapped to the restaurants#show is mapped to the restaurant path.

Is the form_tag piece wrong?

In the instructions from the class we didn't set up anything in routes.rb, I'm guessing that's because of the redirect_to line in the controller file. Is that deprecated now? Is that no longer valid?

Routes file as requested: (in the class exercise we didn't have to edit the routes file).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root 'restaurants#index'

resources :restaurants do
  collection do
    get 'login'
    get 'register'
    post 'newuser'
    post 'validate'
    post 'search'
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: show the `routes` file

Comment: I suggest a look at the documentation, many things have changed and I believe it is best that you study the new framework in general, this documentation you will find everything you need and understood in a better way. [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html)

Comment: that would have never worked. You have no route to submit the form to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You do need a route** for that. The way it works is:

- User fills in a form on some page and sends data to `review` route
- Server processes user's data and returns a redirect to `show` route
- A user gets a redirect and requests the `show` route
- A server executes the `show` action

Apparently the route for `review` action (or as I called it above: a `review` route) doesn't exist in `routes.rb`. Add it.

**UPD:** Your routes file looks really odd, you seem to not follow a common practice to process one type of resources in one controller. Here, you probably need to add:

```
    ...
    post 'search'
    post 'review'
    # ^ THIS ^
  end
end
```

But you already process at least 3 types of resources in one controller: `User`s, `Session`s and `Restaurant`s. This might not be your fault if you were told to do so, but in either case it's not a proper way to structure an application.

Comment: OK. I added `get 'review'` in my collection in the routes.rb file. That did make the page appear. Then when I tried to post I got an error `No route matches POST`. So I then added `post 'review'` to my routes.rb and then I got the error `ActiveModel: Forbidden Attributes error` for this line: `Restaurant.find(params[:id]).reviews.create(params[:review])`

Comment: @JamesWhite see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'review', :id => @restaurant.id do %>
```

Comment: It's unlikely the cause. It's about `to_param` method, that just returns object's `id` in its default implementation. It can be overridden, but I doubt it's the case.

Comment: Don't know if he is using AR or something else but this happens with mongoid for example.

Comment: Not quite. I get this error now `<%= form_tag :action => 'review', :id => @restaurant.id do %>`

Comment: @D-side pretty sure the `to_param` method is automatically called when you use a route helper but not the way he used it. From a ruby perspective it's just creating a plain old hash where the value is an instance instead of an id.