# ForbiddenAttributesError, only in tests, after minor version upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth, strong-parameters

I'm trying to upgrade from Rails 4.1.11 to 4.1.16. Several of my SessionsController specs fail after this upgrade. But when I try to log in in the development environment, everything seems to work fine.

I have the following code:

```
# sessions_controller.rb
def create
  @identity = Identity.find_or_create(auth)
  ...
end

protected

def auth
  request.env["omniauth.auth"]
end

# identity.rb
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.find_or_create(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:uid, :provider)).first_or_create
  end
end
```

In my specs, I use a fixture in `spec_helper.rb` to supply the OmniAuth hash:

```
# spec_helper.rb
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
  :provider => 'facebook',
  :uid => '1234567',
  :info => {
    :email => 'joe@bloggs.com',
    ...
  }
}
```

When I try to use the OmniAuth attributes to find a user's identity, I get a `ForbiddenAttributesError`:

```
1) SessionsController GET :create not yet signed in sets the user ID in the session hash
   Failure/Error: get :create
   ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
     ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
   # /Users/pat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activemodel-4.1.6/lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
```

I understand the idea of strong parameters and whitelisting attributes in the `params` hash. But I can't use `require` on the OmniAuth hash (at least not directly), and I haven't had to in the past.

This is the example provided on [OmniAuth's GitHub page](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    self.current_user = @user
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  protected

  def auth_hash
    request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end
end
```

Presumably, it works with recent versions of Rails.

How can I get my tests to pass? [Here](https://github.com/patbl/skillshare.im) is the rest of the code if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried whitelisting the parameters like this?

```
def auth
  ActionController::Parameters.new(request.env["omniauth.auth"]).permit(...)
end
```

Comment: I tried `ActionController::Parameters.new(request.env["omniauth.auth"]).permit(:provider, :uid, :info)` but that didn't include the `:info` parameter: `undefined method 'info' for {"provider"=>"facebook", "uid"=>"1234567"}:ActionController::ParametersActionController::Parameters...`.

In any case, it would be nice to avoid modifying working code just to get a previously passing test to work. As I mentioned, the current method to retrieve the auth hash is the same as that provided in the documentation, so it seems like the problem is with the tests or Rails, not the controller code.

Comment: That's because `info` has nested parameters. Try with `permit(:provider, :uid, info: [:email])`. I agree it would be nice not having to change working code, but the environment has changed, so your code must adapt to it. OTOH, it's a change for the better, so I wouldn't mind that much. Best!

Comment: In the model in which I use the parameters to create a user, I wrap the auth hash with `OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(auth_hash)`. That way accessing nested hash values with the dot syntax still works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the rspec version in your gemfile to this:

```
gem "rspec-rails", '~> 2.14.0.rc1'
```

Comment: I'm already on RSpec 3.1.0, and it would be inconvenient to downgrade. In any case, it's not clear to me how this would help.

Comment: Could it be related to e.g. this?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user