# Association showing undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models in my rails app, I am trying to associate them

My user model created with Device

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :userdetail

  has_many :posts
  has_many :topics, :through => :posts
end
```

Here is my topic model

```html
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relation between topics and post
  has_many :posts
end
```

Here is my post model

```html
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relation between topics and post
  belongs_to :topic

  belongs_to :user

  #post is valid only if it's associated with a topic:

   validates :topic_id, :presence => true
  #can also require that the referenced topic itself be valid
  #in order for the post to be valid:

  validates_associated :topic



end
```

here is my post controller

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 # before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :has_userdetail_and_topic, :only =>[:new, :create]



  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json

  #for new association SAAS book

  protected
  def has_userdetail_and_topic

    unless(@topic =Topic.find_by_id(params[:topic_id]))
      flash[:warning] = 'post must be for an existing topic'
    end
  end

  public

  def new
    @post = @topic.posts.build
    #@@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id1])

  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new


  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create


    @current_user.posts << @topic.posts.build(params[:post])

    #@topic.posts << @post

    #@post = Post.new(post_params )

    #@post.userdetail_id = current_user.id

     #Association functional between topic and post
     #Class variable used
     #@@topic.posts << @post

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:topic_id,:issue, :description, :rating, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Here is my post new view

```html
<%= form_tag topic_posts_path(@topic) do  %>
    <%= label :post, :description %>
<%= text_area :post, :description %>

    <%= submit_tag 'Create post' %>

<%end%>
```

I am getting this error in post controller.I am not sure why I am getting this error

undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass for  @current_user.posts << @topic.posts.build(params[:post])

I am trying to associate topic and post 
In my topic's show view.

I used the code <%= link_to 'Write', new_topic_post_path(topic_id: @topic) %>

```
<%= link_to 'Write', new_topic_post_path(topic_id: @topic) %>
```

I am using Device for user log in and i haven't setup current_user anywhere in my app.

I want to create a app in which user can create post on topics.
For each topic there is multiple posts.
I am new and learning RoR so please explain answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device provide you with `current_user` helper (without `@`). Use it, instead of `@current_user`.

You may also want to set

```
before_filter :authenticate_user
```

in your post `PostsController` - to be sure that `current_user` isn't nil (and user is logged in correctly).

Also part of create method should be changed:

```
@post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)
@current_user.posts << @post
```

Comment: now its showing ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user
you probably want to read some Rails tutorials...

Comment: IS there any problem in params.require(:post).permit(:topic_id,:issue, :description, :rating, :user_id)

Comment: you're using: params[:post] where you should be using post_params instead

Comment: I understand that post but unable judge where i went wrong

Comment: Oh... silly mistake but I am getting another error now undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass for if @post.save

Comment: You probably want to rewrite some of this code - because now @post is commented. So I would rewrite it to something like (code will be in main post)

Comment: that means object is NIL why ?

Comment: sorry I don't get what do u want to say

Comment: because you commented line of code where you set @post to value ;)

please look at code in answer.

Comment: Thats working but what is wrong with the code format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }

Comment: You probably want to do something like `redirect_to [@topic, @post]` as I understand your routing completely.

also: please avoid word `public` in Ruby class. Instead move `protected` section to the bottom of class (by default everything is public).

Comment: Thanks that's working Please tell me just last thing how can I decide in future that I have to use what redirect_to parameters like u used in redirect_to [@topic, @post] and where to move Protected ?

Comment: You're using nested resource in routing - therefore you must provide **both** component of path to have proper redirect.

About second one - I think you should post your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - they will be more than  happy to help!