# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm stuck on this error and i can't figure out whats wrong.

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @tickets = Newticket.new(params[:tickets])

    @tickets.save
    redirect_to @tickets
  end

  private

  def tickets_params
    params.require(tickets).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

Comment: where is the `tickets` method defined?

Comment: Did you look at any of [the other questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+ActiveModel%3A%3AForbiddenAttributesError) discussing this? Look at the top related ones on the right side of this page too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass `ticket_params` to the `new` method

```
def create
    # your code
    @tickets = Newticket.new(params[:tickets])

    # you should use
    @tickets = Ticket.new(ticket_params) #if your model is named Ticket
    @tickets = Newticket.new(ticket_params) #if your model is named Newticket
    @tickets.save
    redirect_to @tickets
end

private
    def tickets_params
        params.require(:tickets).permit(:title, :text) # if your model is named Ticket
        params.require(:newtickets).permit(:title, :text) # if your model is named Newticket
    end
end
```

you have create method `ticket_params` that is permitting `:tickets` values from `params` hash, and you have said with `permit` which keys are permitted in `params[:tickets]` hash object. You have put `:title, :text`. You problem was that you are using `params[:ticket]` that has none permitted params.

Comment: i think it should be Ticket.new(ticket_params)

Comment: If model is called `Ticket` of course, but he asked for model `Newticket`

Comment: i dont think he has an Ticket and an Newticket (btw. it would be named NewTicket) model.

Answer (score 0):

@tickets = Newticket.new(params[:tickets])

Newticket.new that one was causing the troubles. I defined that method wrong earlier when generating the controllers i called it Newticket while i should have called it tickets.

Thanks for in the input.