# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) in a rails app with two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, arguments

I keep getting 'a wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)' error and it seems like such a broad error that I can't seem to narrow down what the cause of it is.

I am making an appointment app that records a date range (start_date, end_date) in a table called Project.  When a new Project is created, a ProjectDate record is generated for every date in the range between start_date and end_date (ie. Feb.1 -Feb. 7 creates 7 ProjectDate records).

The line that the error appears on is: " if @project.update_attributes"

I'm fairly new to rails and so I don't really understand why it's not passing an argument.  My theory is that maybe I have the form_for url path wrong...but I don't know how.

Projects Controller (where the error appears)

```
def edit_date_range 
 @project = Project.find(params[:p])
end

def update_date_range 
 @project = Project.find(params[:p])
   if @project.update_attributes
    redirect_to  k1s3_path(:p => @project.id)
  else
   redirect_to  edit_date_range_path(:p => @project.id)
 end
end
```

Models

```
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :project_dates, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :project
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_dates, allow_destroy: true

 after_update :add_and_remove_dates

def dates_in_date_range
  (self.prep_start.to_date .. self.prep_end.to_date.to_a)
end

def add_and_remove_dates
  dates.where('schedule_date < ? OR schedule_date > ?', start_date, end_date).destroy_all
  dates_in_date_range.each do |date|
  dates.find_or_create_by(schedule_date: date, available: true)
  end  
end

  class ProjectDates < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :project_dates
```

Table Structures

```
Project table structure
  :id 
  :title (string)
  :start_date (date)
  :end_date(date)
  :status (boolean)

ProjectDates table structure
  :id 
  :project_id (integer)
  :schedule_date (date)
  :available (boolean)
```

form

```
  <%= form_for @project, url: update_date_range_path(:p => @project.id) do |f| %>  

  <%= f.hidden_field :org_start, :value => @project.start_date %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :org_end, :value => @project.end_date %>
  <%=  f.text_field  :end_date %>
  <%=  f.text_field  :start_date%>

  <%= f.submit 'SAVE CHANGES' %>       

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any parameters to the `update_attributes` method, which expects 1 param (usually a hash containing everything that needs to be updated). Hence the `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error message.

Change:

```
if @project.update_attributes
```

to

```
if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
```

`project_params` would be the private method that sets the needed parameters as required

```
private
def project_params
   params.require(:project).permit(<attr1>, <attr2>, <attr3>...)
end
```

Comment: That gives me this:" ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError "

Comment: I checked and I am passing params into the method...this is where I'm confused.

Comment: `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` is because of not marking the parameters as required. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user

Comment: I'm using   params.require(:project).permit! , so they should all be good.

Comment: I am already using def project_params
   params.require(:project).permit!
end

Comment: Thank you. That fixed that error.  I have another...but it's not related.