# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError while creating a new entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I was trying to create a simple app when I ended up having a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @posts = Post.all       
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @post =Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if  @post.save
        redirect_to post_path,:notice=>"success"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
end

def destroy
end

private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:Title, :content)
    end

end
```

I have seen a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user) but the solution for that did not fix my issue.

My version of rails is 4.2.0.

The error displayed is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that `params[:post]` hash (or any `params[*]` hash) directly in any mass-assignment method, you need to use a `permit` call so Rails knows you've checked it and to allow it.

So, change your `Post.new` to `@post = Post.new(post_params)`

Comment: hey that fixed that issue , now it shows  at the line         
redirect_to post_path,:notice=>"success"      with the error message displaying as       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]       I am trying to line it to the previous page where it displays the new post entered ,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Asking followup questions in comments on answers that you haven't even upvoted despite finding them useful leaves people with a bad impression of you. Please take some time and read the help especially [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). And you really should ask your new question as a new question, not in the comments on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Change `@post = Post.new(params[:post])` to `@post = Post.new(post_params)`.

Comment: hey that fixed that issue , now it shows  at the line         
redirect_to post_path,:notice=>"success"      with the error message displaying as       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]       I am trying to line it to the previous page where it displays the new post entered ,

Comment: Please add a new question when you have a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
def create
  @post = Post.new post_params
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Created new post"
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(posts_params)
  if  @post.save
    redirect_to post_path,:notice=>"success"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

private

def posts_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:Title, :content)
end
```