# Ruby Depot Application

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to depot app for Ruby on Rails and my Orders_Controller isn't working properly, it's saying `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`. I believe it has to do something with my `orders_controller`:

```
 def create
     @order = Order.new(params[:order])
     @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)

Comment: Okay, yeah it's highlighting @Order.new(params[:order]) saying ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Comment: You might be using a forbidden name as your column name, e.g. 'type'. Check your schema.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't help you [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user) pls. give more info incl. Rails version and the number of the line this error occurs at.

Comment: You need to make params required. See the accepted answer in the link in my answer or in @Doguita's answer.