# #500 error with a simple Ruby on Rails and Angularjs project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, general-network-error

thank you al for taking the time to help me with this issue.  I am new to Ruby so this may seem like a simple answer.  I created an api to allow Ruby and Angularjs to talk to each other.  API below:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json
protect_from_forgery

def index
    respond_with Entry.all
end

def show
    respond_with Entry.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    respond_with Entry.create(params[:entry])
end

def update
    respond_with Entry.update(params[:id], params[entry])
end

def destroy
    respond_with Entry.destroy(params[:id])
end
end
```

My angular js controller is:

```
@app = angular.module("angRails",["ngResource", "ngMaterial", "ngAnimate", "ngAria"]);

@mainCTRL = ["$scope", "$resource", ($scope, $resource) ->

  Entry = $resource("/entries/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})

  $scope.newName = "";

  $scope.entries = Entry.query();


  $scope.addEntry = ->

unless $scope.newName is ""
  entry = Entry.save($scope.newName)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(entry));
  $scope.entries.push(entry);
  console.log("add Entry function");
  $scope.newName = "";

]


app.controller("mainCTRL", mainCTRL);
```

The `$scope.entries = Entry.query();`  works completely fine but the create entry is not working at all.  I get the error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/entries 500 (Internal Server Error)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in EntriesController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Extracted source (around line #14):
12
13 def create
14 respond_with Entry.create(params[:entry])
15 end
```

I am not sure why I get this error.  i am grateful with any help I can get.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear from your controller that you are not allowing/accounting for [strong params](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

In your controller, you need a method that indicates which params are allowed for your model.

```
def create
  @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
  @entry.save
  respond_with(@entry)
end 

private 
def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:attribute, :another_attribute)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `ForbiddenAttributesError`

You need to explicity specify which params are whitelisted for mass-updating:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

This is a solution to a similar problem:
[ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)