# Rails 5.0 Error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to make a blog post on my web-app updatable from the browser, but when I click update in the edit for, I get this error:
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

error in pots_controller line 33:

if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])

this is my edit.html.erb code:

```
<h1>Edit Post</h1>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :body %><br />
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => "Select One"} %><br />
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Update post" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Go Back", post_path %>
```

this is my posts_controller.rb code:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.find(4,5)
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
        @category = Category.all

    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(params[:post])
        if @post.save
            redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been saved"
        else
            render "new"
        end

    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])           
            redirect_to post_path, :notice => "Your post has been updated"
        else 
            render "edit"
        end 

    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been deleted"
    end

end
```

hope and thank anyone can help. Best, M

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Strong Parameters

Rails uses a security mechanism called Strong Parameters by default. Its purpose is to ensure that only certain fields can be updated via a user submitted form.

`@post.update_attributes(params[:post])` is an old-style syntax which does not work with strong parameters.

The updated convention is as follows

```
class PostsController
  def update
    # ...
    @post.update(post_params) # instead of passing params[:post] directly, you pass it a strong parameters whitelist (see below)
  end

  def post_params
    # we construct a strong parameters whitelist below
    # require(:post) means that the `params` hash MUST contain a :post key
    # permit(:title, :body, ...) = here we enumerate the attributes which we will accept from the form parameters; it acts as a whitelist
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, ...) 
  end
end
```

If you use `rails g scaffold` you can see an example of a controller which uses strong parameters.

**DON'T DO THIS**: To disable using strong parameters by default, you can set the following config value

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

I included this for completeness' sake, however you should not do this as it will unnecessarily introduce security vulnerabilities to your code.

### Additional Resources

- [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)
- http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html
- https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters