# Contact won't work due to Rails 5 update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, upgrade, contact-form

I'm Working on upgrading a Rails 3v project to 5v. Everything seems to be working but I get this error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ContactsController#create
>
> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
>
> @contact = Contact.new params[:contact]

Here is My Model:

```
  class Contact < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :contactable, :polymorphic => true  
      attribute :contact
      validates :email, :presence => true
      validates :name, :presence => true
      validates :body, :presence => true
    
      validates :email, email: true, allow_blank: true
  
    
      scope :are_read, -> { where("state = ? ","read") }
      scope :are_unread, -> { where("state = ?","unread") }
    
      state_machine :state, :initial => :unread do
        event :reading do
          transition :unread => :read
        end
      end
    end
and
```

Here is my Controller:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    if params[:product].present?
      @contact.contactable = Product.find params[:product]
    end

    if params[:rental].present?
      @contact.contactable = Rental.find params[:rental]
    end
  end
  def create
#    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @contact = Contact.new params[:contact]
    if @contact.save
      UserMailer.contact_notification(@contact).deliver
      redirect_to thanks_contact_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def thanks

  end
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user

Maybe you need to permit the params that you are allowing - did you just upgrade direct to 5.x from 3.x? If not, your tests should have failed in 4.x so could be something else

Answer (score 3):

Try to the following to create a `private` method with [Rails strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) under the `controller`

```
private

def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :body)
end
```

Change like this

```
def create
   @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
   ....
end
```

instead of this

```
@contact = Contact.new params[:contact]
```

Comment: I fixed it with adding this 
def contact_params
 params.require(:contact).permit(:contactable_type, :contactable_id,:name, :email, :body, :phone) 
end

Comment: If helping you with this answer please mark as accepted for future help

Comment: Yes already done, but couldn't vote cause I need 15 reputation,

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 onwards you cannot use params directly for mass assignment. 
You need to use [**`Strong Params`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) to whitelist the parameters.

```
@contact = Contact.new params[:contact]
```

Use

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  ...
end

private

def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:contact, :params, :attributes_here) # <= Change this
end
```