# Ruby on Rails - Send contact form - Controller issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

I have a contact form in my project with Ruby on Rails (Ruby 2.4.0 and Rails 5.2.0). When I try send the form, the following error occurs:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
  app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

I suspect that errors is in contact controller, as the error says.

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def index 
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if @contact.save
      ContactMailer.delay_for(10.seconds, retry: true).create(@contact)
      render nothing: true, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end

end
```

In some older versions of Ruby and Rails the same code works fine. Anything change for the recent versions? Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)

Comment: You need to use a new approach of params processing called strong params. Can you paste what exact fields does your contact form contains?

Comment: `Contact.new(params[:contact])` <--- You cannot do this; rails, by default, protects assigning parameters directly. They need to be "whitelisted" (or, you need to explicitly say "whitelist everything").

Comment: Can you run your website in "development" mode, so you can get a stack trace instead of a 500 error? What does your log file say? And what do your automated tests say about your `create` action?

Comment: Suppose you have an attribute `contact.is_admin (true/false)`. Your current code would allow the user to set this value without protection - which is probably not what you intended! This is why rails requires you to define which attributes can be set, via `permit`.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Alexande's answer (in below) helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should change it in some kind of this way:

```
class ContactsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def index 
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      ContactMailer.delay_for(10.seconds, retry: true).create(@contact)
      render nothing: true, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :phone)
  end

end
```

You can read more detailed about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) and [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Comment: This worked in parts. I needed to create a view in contacts called "create" too. Now is working fine. In some older version of Ruby on Rails this it wasn't necessary.

Thanks fot the help!