# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in UserController#register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

Im trying to register users on my rails site. When I click the register button on the register page this is what shows up:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in UserController#register
>   ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Here is the code for my `user_controller.rb` file:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title = "RailsSpace User Hub"
  end

  def register
    @title = "Register"
    if request.post? and params[:user]
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
    end
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "User #{@user.screen_name} created!"
      redirect_to :action => "index"
    end
  end
end
```

It's complaining about line 11: `@user = User.new(params[:user])` Im following code from a book so I dont know what's wrong with it.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [strong parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

The UserController should look like this:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title = "RailsSpace User Hub"
  end

  def register
    @title = "Register"
    if request.post? and params[:user]
      @user = User.new(user_params)
    end
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "User #{@user.screen_name} created!"
      redirect_to :action => "index"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    # Add the user attributes that you sent with post (form) to the permit method.
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :screen_name)
  end
end
```