# No values are given to db-query after swicthing to strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, redmine-plugins

I am trying to get this [redmine-plugin](https://github.com/JostBaron/redmine_workload) to work in redmine4.x.

I made [my own repo](https://github.com/mboremski/redmine_workload) to manage all changes.

I already managed to get the plugin running by [replacing attr_accessible by attr_accessor](https://github.com/mboremski/redmine_workload/commit/f4bfeb0e1c5df8f5e4235a7537046f6d1b5355af) and changing to strong parameters by applying things given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user).

At this state the plugin runs with no errors in redmine 4.x

BUT: Now I am struggeling to save things to database.
I found that for some reason the parameters that has to be saved are not handed over to the query:

`INSERT INTO wl_user_vacations VALUES ()`

Here is the code used:

```
class WlUserVacationsController < ApplicationController
[...]
  def create
    @wl_user_vacation = WlUserVacation.new(wl_user_vacations)
    @wl_user_vacation.user_id = User.current.id
    if @wl_user_vacation.save
      redirect_to action: 'index', notice: 'Vacation was successfully saved.', year: params[:year]
    else
      respond_to do |format| 
        format.html {lash[:error] = "<ul>" + @wl_user_vacation.errors.full_messages.map{|o| "<li>" + o + "</li>" }.join("") + "</ul>" render :action => 'new' }
      format.api  { render_validation_errors(@wl_user_vacation) }
    end 
  end
end

private
[...]
  def wl_user_vacations
    params.require(:wl_user_vacations).permit(:user_id,:date_from,:date_to,:comments,:vacation_type)
  end
end
```

Saving fails on `@wl_user_vacation.save` in `create` with:

```
Processing by WlUserVacationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"*********", "wl_user_vacations"=>{"date_from(3i)"=>"7", "date_from(2i)"=>"12", "date_from(1i)"=>"2019", "date_to(3i)"=>"7", "date_to(2i)"=>"12", "date_to(1i)"=>"2019", "comments"=>"", "vacation_type"=>""}, "year"=>"", "commit"=>"Hinzufügen"}
  Current user: boremski (id=10)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)

ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (Mysql2::Error: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `wl_user_vacations` VALUES ()):

plugins/redmine_workload/app/controllers/wl_user_vacations_controller.rb:38:in `create'
```

If needed I can share more code or even some debug-iformations (vaiable-values and more).

Is anyone able to help or give me a hint?

*Edit*:
Some debug-output:

```
self: W1UserVacationsController
    @_action_has_layout: true
    @_action_name: 'create'
    @_config: Empty #<Class:Ox0000564e86153080>
    @_lookup_context: ActionView::LookupContext 
    @_params: rutf8'=>"V", "authenticity_tokena=>"*********"
        @parameters: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (7 elements)
            'utf8': 'authenticity_token': '*********' 
            'wl_user_vacations': {"date_from(3i)-=>"8", "date_from(20-W12", ”date_from(1i)"W21 ‘,[...]
                @parameters: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (8 elements)
                    'date_from(3i)': '8'
                    'date_from(2i)': '12'
                    'date_from(li)': '2019'
                    'date_to(3i)': '8'
                    'date_to(2i)': '12'
                    'date_to(li)': '2019'
                    'comments': ''
                    'vacation_type': ''
                @permitted: false
                @@action_on_unpermitted_parameters: false
                @@always_permitted_parameters: Array (2 elements)
                @@permit_all_parameters: false
                'year': ''
                'commit': 'Hinzufügen'
                'controller': 'wl_user_vacations'
                'action': 'create'
```

Comment: You're not sending the needed `user_id` where making the request. Check that.

Comment: I am (/ the code is) not sending **any** parameters in the query. Thats the problem.
The mysql-error only refers to `user_id` because it is a mandatory field.

Comment: Did you see the params? It clearly shows no `user_id`. Check the form you're using or whatever to perform the request.

Comment: What params do you mean pls? :-) one line above the `save` action the `user_id` is set with `@wl_user_vacation.user_id = User.current.id`

Comment: Those, what you added in your question (`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"*********", "wl_user_vacations"=>{"date_from(3i)"=>"7", "date_from(2i)"=>"12", "date_from(1i)"=>"2019", "date_to(3i)"=>"7", "date_to(2i)"=>"12", "date_to(1i)"=>"2019", "comments"=>"", "vacation_type"=>""}, "year"=>"", "commit"=>"Hinzufügen"}`), If so, what's the value of `User.current.id` at that point?

Comment: It's easier for you just to place a breakpoint (pry, byebug, etc) and see what's happening there.

Comment: Isn't `wl_user_vacations` being defined in any other place?

Comment: Edited question. Added some debug-output

Comment: `User.current.id` is 10 (user: boremski). `@wl_user_vacation.user_id` also is 10.

Comment: You can check `wl_user_vacations.to_h` to get only permitted parameters, see if the parameters are there.

Comment: This has: `wl_user_vacations.to_h: {"date_from(3i)"=>"8", "date_from(2i)"=>"12", "date_from(1i)"=>"2019", "date_to(3i)"=>"8", "date_to(2i)"=>"12", "date_to(1i)"=>"2019", "comments"=>"", "vacation_type"=>""}`. I dont know how to add missing `user_id` here. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The values are not being passed to the save function here.
Can you share the form being used for create ?

```
def wl_user_vacations params.require(:wl_user_vacations).permit(:user_id,:date_from,:date_to,:comments,:vacation_type).tap do |param| 
param['user_id'] = current_user.id 
end 
end
```

Above code should do, for adding the user_id.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to edit my question.
Here ist one line from the form:
`<%= form.date_select :date_from, default: { year: @this_year} %>`

Comment: `def wl_user_vacations  params.require(:wl_user_vacations).permit(:user_id,:date_from,:date_to,:comments,:vacation_type).tap do |param|  param['user_id'] = current_user.id end
  end` . The above code should do the trick to add user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem/solution:

while switching to strong parameters i did not remove

```
attr_accessor :user_id  
attr_accessor :date_from
attr_accessor :date_to
attr_accessor :comments
attr_accessor :vacation_type
```

from my model-file.
After commenting this values are saved to db.

Thank you all for your help!