# Ruby on Rails creating multiple children in one parent form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parent-child, fields-for

I have a parent which has multiple children. I want it so that when I submit my form, a parent is generated in the parent model, and multiple records are created in the child model, one for each child. When I try and submit, I get the following error:

```
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ParentsController#create

   Child(#) expected, got Array(#)
```

When I uncomment accepts_nested_attributes_for :children and change f.fields_for :children to f.fields_for :children_attributes, I get a different error:

```
  TypeError in ParentsController#create

    can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

I am at a loss as to what to do. I have checked out the nested model forms railscasts, but they were dealing with generating children fields inside the form, and what I learned from the railscasts didn't seem to work. I am pretty I am doing my builder.text_field :cname's in my form wrong, but I'm not aware of the proper way to do it.

My code:

parent.rb

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
  attr_protected :id
```

child.rb

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  attr_protected :id
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @parent, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :pname %>
  <%= f.fields_for :children do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :cname %>
    <%= builder.text_field :cname %>
    <%= builder.text_field :cname %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

params content:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"FQQ1KdNnxLXolfes9IGiO+aKHJaPCH+2ltDdA0TwF7w=",
 "parent"=>{"pname"=>"Heman",
 "child"=>{"cname"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

Comment: Can you post the `params` containing the attributes for children, when you submit the form, please? I'm pretty sure you just have to loop on the `params[:children]` since your error log tells us it is an Array

Comment: @MrYoshiji you might come to my rescue yet again. I have updated my question with the params. Only one child appears and it doesn't display any names.

Comment: Ah, I recognize this... Give me a minute, I post an answer, while you can take a look at this very similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919711/multiple-non-nested-model-creation-on-same-page/16920211#16920211

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem here is** that the generated form in HTML for the children are using the same "place" (same pair key/value) in the params Hash (using the `params[:parent][:child][:cname]` pair). This is why there is only one param 'name' in the 'child' node in the Params hash.

**To avoid that**, you can use an array for the input's name:

```
<input type="text" name="child[][cname]" />
<input type="text" name="child[][cname]" />
```

The params, when this submitted, will look like this:

```
params: {
  child: [ { cname: 'blabla' }, { cname: 'bonjour' } ]
}
```

To get the desired result, **in your case**:

```
<%= form_for @parent, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :pname %>

  <%= text_field_tag "parent[children][][cname]" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "parent[children][][cname]" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "parent[children][][cname]" %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Should produce something like this:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"FQQ1KdNnxLXolfes9IGiO+aKHJaPCH+2ltDdA0TwF7w=",
  "parent"=> { 
    "pname"=>"Heman",
    "children"=> [
      { "cname"=>"SisiSenior" },
      { "cname"=>"Bonjor" },
      { "cname"=>"Blabla" }
    ]
  },
  "commit"=>"Create"}
```

So in your controller, you could use something like this:

```
#ParentsController
def create
  children_attributes = params[:parent].delete(:children) # takes off the attributes of the children
  @parent = Parent.create(params[:parent])

  children_attributes.each do |child_attributes|
    child = @parent.children.create(child_attributes)
  end
end
```

Comment: holy buckets mate. you're a life saver. Thanketh so mucheth. And of course, may your sword stay sharp and your steed be quick.

Comment: sorry about this but i figured it was too simple to be a new question. is there a way to make it to only create the record if name isnt blank? I figured it would work to just use an if #something != nil child=@parent.children.create(child_attributes) end, but I don't know what to put instead of #something.

Comment: nevermind i figured it out. i replaced #something != nil with child_attributes["name"] != ""