# Multiple non-nested model creation on same page with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using this good answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16920211/4412054

in my project:

**_form.html.erb**:

```
= form_tag({controller: "users", action: "create"}, remote: true) do
  %table
    %tr
      %td= text_field_tag 'user[][first_name]'
      %td= text_field_tag 'user[][last_name]'

    %tr.actions
      %td= submit_tag 'Save'
      %td= button_tag 'Add new user form', id: 'add_user_form'

    %tr.new_user_row.hidden # hidden class matches the css rule: {display:none;}
      %td= text_field_tag "user[][first_name]"
      %td= text_field_tag "user[][last_name]"

:javascript # jQuery
  $('#add_user_form').bind('click', function(e) {
    var row = $('tr.new_user_row').clone().removeClass('hidden new_user_row');
    $('tr.actions').before(row); # will append the <tr> before the actions
  });
```

and **UsersController**:

```
def create
  params[:user].each do |attr|
    User.create(attr)
  end
end
```

but when I submit it give me this error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

If I disable Rails 4 `strong_parameters` by `config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters = true` in *config/application.rb* it works and save.

**How to permit the hash**

`..., "user"=>[{"first_name"=>"Name", "last_name"=>"Last"}, {"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>""}],....`

*in my controller?*

**UPDATE**

If I use in Rails console:

`User.create({"first_name"=>"Name", "last_name"=>"Last"})`

it works!!!

**UPDATE 2**

In my controller I have this:

```
def users_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:user, array: [:first_name, :last_name])
end
```

Comment: What are your current allowed params?

Comment: I tried anything but nothing happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params.permit(:user, array: [
  :last_name,
  :first_name,
])
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30285592/484130

UPDATE:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def users_params
    params.permit(user: [:last_name, :first_name])["user"]
  end

  def some_action
    @users = Array.new

    users_params.each do |user_params|
      user = User.new user_params
      @users.push user if user.save
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  ....

end
```

This should work.
And sorry for not test it myself..

BTW, gem `byebug` is your best friend.

Comment: Nothing, again: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 129ms (ActiveRecord: 36.2ms)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
  activemodel (4.2.5) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'`

Comment: @JohnSam I have tested and updated the answer, sorry for previous one which I didn't test it myself.

Comment: Dear @Francis.TM, here we are again in trouble. Like before: `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:`

Comment: @JohnSam I have give a full example that which I have tested.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks, but why I have to use this strange code `params.permit(user: [:last_name, :first_name])["user"]`? I can't use simple and standard `def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(user: [:last_name, :first_name])
    end`??

Comment: @JohnSam Rails 4 don't let you use form params directly into a db query, you need permit it first. so we need a `params.permit`, just like a whitelist. detail you can check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit .

Comment: How can I check if at least one of them is saved? Other words how can I use the standard: `respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save.........`

Comment: Dear @Francis.TM, everything works now. Just one question now. How can I group by :lastname, or `:firstname` and save records with sum of every row grouped by one attribute and an attribute "count" (count column is there already in database, but I need one record total for the same lastname in `@users`)? Sorry the mess!

Comment: And then a curiosity, instead of save every each per time, how to save one time with a big INSERT query?

Comment: @JohnSam You can see https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/ for mass inserting information.