# Rails: ForbiddenAttributesError for dynamic simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I followed the answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919711/multiple-non-nested-model-creation-on-same-page) to create a simple dynamic form (not nested). The idea is to invite several people with their email. Then I have an "Add Team Member" button to add the fields to enter the coworker email.

I get the following error but I don't know why:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in InvitationsController#create

The parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"zLs8DWkzO+bPc2jGhFptgc+BAGAwzr1kcn/hkX/6vQbQ/cDCzuqoGCMGUTcYHs+up7nBzHFiEXVcKustyL1KIA==",
 "invitation"=>[{"email"=>"test@test.fr", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_id"=>"1"}, {"email"=>"test2@test2.fr", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_id"=>"1"}],
 "commit"=>"Save Team Members"}
```

My create action and invitation_params in the controller:

```
def create
    puts params[:invitation].to_yaml
    params[:invitation].each do |invitation_params|
     Invitation.create(invitation_params)
    end
    redirect_to invitation_path
  end

def invitation_params
      params.require(:invitation).permit(:id, :email, :user_id, :_destroy, :token)
    end
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for(invitation) do |f| %>
  <% if invitation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(invitation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this invitation from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% invitation.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div id="container_invitations"></div>

  <%= link_to "Add a New Team Member", add_invitation_path, :method => :post, :remote => true %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save Team Members", class: "cta2" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

add_invitation controller action (to add the fields dynamically):

```
def add_invitation
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

add_invitation.js.erb:

```
$('#container_invitations').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'invitation_fields_render') %>");
$('.remove_fields').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

_invitation_fields_render.html.erb (the partial with the fields)

```
<div class="new_invitation_row">
 <%= email_field_tag "invitation[][email]", nil, placeholder: "Team Member Email", :required => 'required' %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "invitation[][_destroy]", nil, value: false %>
 <a class="remove-link remove_fields dynamic" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" title="Remove"></i></a>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "invitation[][user_id]", nil, value: current_user.id %>
</div>
```

My invitation model:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_token

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thank you.

UPDATE

I added the new params.permit line proposed by IngoAlbers. I still get the error. Here is the full stacktrace of the error:

> Started POST "/invitations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-01 07:49:02 +0000
>   Processing by InvitationsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"pV5wQj3QHXksNEtJ8nZSjWDc8VyHiewVCt4A1+ijH8G5GIyNmgmOh8BBcrhuMvCiCOQw8MYlQAQkiwprX+To5w==",
>   "invitation"=>[{"email"=>"test@test.fr", "_destroy"=>"false",
>   "user_id"=>"1"}], "commit"=>"Save Team Members"}   User Load (0.4ms) 
>   SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY
>   "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]   CoreBot Load
>   (0.2ms)  SELECT  "core_bots".* FROM "core_bots" WHERE "core_bots"."id"
>   = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
>
> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
>   (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
>   app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:35:in `block in create'
>   app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:34:in`each'
>   app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:34:in `create'   Rendering
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout   Rendering
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
>   Rendered
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
>   (5.3ms)   Rendering
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb   Rendered
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.5ms)   Rendering
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   Rendered
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   (1.5ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout (93.1ms)

Comment: Can you please try to set `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :log` in your environment file? (probably config/environments/development.rb). Then check and paste the logs again. We can see then on which parameters it fails.

Comment: I added it in my environment file and updated the logs but it seems it's the same..

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually have it in the environment file with value `:raise`? If you are sure try restarting the server.

Comment: I checked, it's :log, I restarted the server but still the same logs.

Comment: Ok I misinterpreted something here, think I got it now. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `invitation` is an array. So you actually need to permit the array in the `invitation_params`.

```
def invitation_params
  params.permit(invitation: [:id, :email, :user_id, :_destroy, :token])
end
```

In addition you have a problem in the create action itself.
You don't actually use the permitted parameters, that was defined.
It should probably look like this:

```
def create
  invitation_params[:invitation].each do |invitation|
    Invitation.create(invitation)
  end

  redirect_to invitation_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just changed the params.permit line but I still get the same error. Do you have any idea in mind to debug this?

Comment: I added the stacktrace in the post.

Comment: Ok so now I get the following: undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x007f86024d5960>