# Rails - Add multiple records in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model and Todo model. I want to be able to add multiple todos using a single form.

**Routes:**

```
# Users
  resources(:users) do
    resources(:todos)
  end
```

**User model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :todos
    ....
```

**Todos controller:**

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @todos = Array.new(10) {@user.todos.build}
    end
    ....
```

**View for todos/new:**

```
<%= form_for([@user, :todos]) do |f| %>
    <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
        <%= f.text_field(:name, class: "form-control") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

What I get is:

```
undefined method `model_name' for :todos:Symbol
```

What am I doing wrong? I searched SO for doing multiple saves using one form, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641565/rails-3-submit-a-form-with-multiple-records).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for nested forms.

In your model you will add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos
```

and in your view

```
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  TODO:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :todo do |todo| %>
      <li>
        <%= todo.label :todo %>
        <%= todo.text_field :todo %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>


    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

in controller

```
def new
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        10.times {@user.todos.build}
    end
```

for refference   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

NOTE: this code is untested

Answer (score 0):

In your view, try

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.todos]) do |f| %>
```

I'm also new to ruby but hopefully it works.